# How to cancel ajax request in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I have a ajax upload using jquery and php for the server side. I have a cancel button which cancels the upload which cancels the ajax request. For that I used jqXHR.abort(); to abort the request. But I have a problem, although the ajax request is aborted, the file still gets uploaded i.e the request which it had made earlier stills gets completed.
How will I be able to cancel the upload process also on aborting the ajax request. Is it possible?
I am using simple file upload with php that uses move_uploaded_file(file,newloc) function to upload the file and blueimp jquery file upload for ajax upload 
( https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Comment: Are you sure that the entire file is uploaded or just a portion of it ? Whatever it might be, after aborting the request, send another request to delete the file if it exists.

Comment: yes the entire file is being uploaded plus i have a database insert after the upload is completed.

Comment: no the js file is not compressed. on making another request, what if the delete request gets completed earlier than the request which uploaded it? it is a possibility? also the uploaded file has a random name, how can i get the file name without knowing it. that makes sending delete request almost absurd. any other way

Comment: Can it help to use if (!connection_aborted()) move_uploaded_file($file,$newloc); Not tested it with ajax.

Comment: If your user has active session, then if you save session id with filename on database then you can easyly manipulate another request what says "abort" and delete file data. Sadly it takes unnessecery room in database. Or you can put that info to different table with timestam and use a service to delete all data from that table if session is ended. If you use session data saveing into database then you can write trigger for deletion.

Comment: this would solve getting the file name but what about in case like this: user adds file and uploads and here is what i display while uploading in brackets (uploading..... cancel button). If the user presses cancel button, as u say i abort the request and then send another request to delete the file. There may be a case when uploading request has not completed and thus there will be no file uploaded, and the request to delete will not find the uploaded file and delete it. This is the problem when the upload request completes after the delete request. I guess i have to remove cancel option